# Having a GAN interact with a mail server?

Tags: python, email, machine-learning, server, generative-adversarial-network

I'm interested in starting a project which involves using machine learning to purely generate quotes, and then having a Mail Server which sends an email to contacts containing the quote created. I'm trying to expand on the idea of a quote of the day server using machine learning, as I'm new to machine learning and networking and would like to play around with both.

From what I have gathered, I am going to want to use a GAN (generative adversarial network) for generating quotes, and to train a GAN I can follow certain steps:

1. Sample a noise set and a real-dataset of the same size
2. Train the discriminator on that data
3. Sample a different noise subset with the same size
4. Train the generator on this data
5. Repeat the steps

However, I cannot find much information on how to make this algorithm communicate with a server like the quote of the day mail server I mentioned I wanted to build. I'm wondering if anyone can assist me with figuring out the steps and process involved with the connecting of machine learning to a server like this!

I'm trying to build an outline of what I need to do, any guidance or references would be awesome!